# With an Azure WebJob with QueueTrigger, does setting a schedule have any effect?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJob that has a QueueTrigger setup (so the task will run when an item is detected in the appropriate storage queue. When uploading the task, I'm unclear as to if I'm supposed to choose Run continuously, Run on a schedule, or Run on demand. If I select run on a schedule, does the task restart and perform the Main() function each iteration, then wait for triggers?

I would like the job to run setup once, and then essentially wait for triggers. I tried searching for documentation, but haven't found any guidance on this, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After doing a bunch of trial and error (also, definitely don't do schedule, it resulted in some phantom webjobs that continued pulling from queues even after they were deleted), it seems like `Continuous` is the right way to go for queue triggered Web Jobs.

Comment: If you want triggers, you **must** use continuous

Comment: Hi I need the answer to this question.....was the above trial and error the definitive result? Thanks in advance. Is it correct that triggers need Continuous.

Comment: Hi @Sentinel - yes, if you need Queue Triggers, you *must* setup a continuous job.